# Pros and Cons of using DatastoreService vs PersistentManager for GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am working on an application with GAE using Java. Would really appreciate if anyone can explain the pros and cons of using DatastoreService vs PersistentManager for datastore access.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

DatastoreService - low level API. PersistentManager (JDO) - high level API that is based on DatastoreService.

Performance: DatastoreService  consumes less resources, PersistentManager (JDO) - has some overhead.

Development: PersistentManager  much more faster for development/support.

Another option that is promised to be faster in performance than JDO and faster in development than low level api - Objectify. This is new promising technology. Try it.